How to get partition values written to Delta efficiently?
I would like to get the set of partition values in a write operation using spark and delta-lake in a partitioned dataset.
Note: the dataset will be very big and with many partitions.
data.write.format("delta").partitionBy("DATE", "GENRE").save()

And get:
DATE=2024-03-01/GENRE=Female
DATE=2024-03-01/GENRE=Male
....

Currently I do:
val partitionCols = Seq("DATE", "GENRE") // Multiple partitions
dataset.mapPartitions { partition =>
  partition.map { row =>
    val partitionValues = partitionCols.map { partition =>
        (partition, Option(row.get(row.fieldIndex(partition))).getOrElse("").toString)
    }
    setAccumulator.add(partitionValues)
    row
  }
}

Which is not very efficient considering I have to go through all data.
I know Delta knows this data because it is written into the DeltaLog. So far this is what I tried:

I could load the DeltaLog from the version or timestamp of my write and iterate over the actions an maybe get the partitionValues. I'm not sure how efficient it would be, or reliable if someone else has written in between.

I also know that if I checkpoint with the option delta.checkpoint.writeStatsAsStruct I will get a parquet file with a partitionValues_parsed which is what I want, but I'm not sure about the cost of checkpointing. And if no one had checkpointed before, would it have values of previous writes?

I know about the change data feed option .option("readChangeFeed", "true") but I cannot be sure that the changes are only from my write operation, and it will still load all my data written and will have to do the same iteration as in my previous code, since it loads a dataframe with ALL the data written, not only partition columns.

The _symlink_format_manifest option, but I will have to read all the folders and I think delete the folders prior to the write operation in case there are from a previous write.


Seeing Delta source code, I know during write it has the values of all the partitions affected. But I don't see a way of retrieving them efficiently.
There is a PostCommitHook class that maybe I could use to get all the affected files after a write, but I don't know where to add it.
Does someone know how could I get them from the delta operation?
Thanks
